# definition of c-command and government

Tags: syntax, government-and-binding

Both definitions are from Syntax; A generative introduction (4th edit.)

c-command: Node A c-commands node B if every 'branching' node dominating A also dominates B, and neither A nor B dominate the other.

Q1) What would be wrong or different if we assume that definition of c-command does not include 'branching'?

government: Node A governs node B if A c-commands B and there is no node G such that G is c-commanded by A and G asymmetrically c-commands B.

Q2) What would be wrong or different if we assume that definition of goverment does not include 'G asymmetrically c-commands B'?

Can you explain with some of samples? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

1 matters if your theory requires non-branching nodes. For example, some theories of syntax insist that every phrase have a separate XP and X level (and sometimes also an X' level in the middle), even if their content is exactly the same as the next level down.

[image: tree showing "empty" levels]

If the definition of C-command doesn't include the "branching" stipulation, then "John" doesn't C-command "himself", because "John" is dominated by the NP node and "himself" is not. And one reason to define C-commanding at all is for reflexive pronouns: we say that the "-self" pronouns have to be C-commanded by their antecedents.

2 matters for case assignment, which is one of the original reasons to propose government as a relationship.

[image: tree showing an embedded clause]

We want the object of a verb to become "her", but the subject of an embedded clause to remain "she". So this theory defines government such that "John" governs "himself" in the first example, but does not govern "she" in the second example (the "that" gets in the way). Intuitively, something is governed only by the head that selected it.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Sorry but could you please explain second matters (definition of government) with another example...? It a bit hard for me to understand.

Comment: We want the pronoun "she" to turn into "her" in "he saw her", but not in "he saw that she was there". So we define government such that "saw" governs "her" in the first example, but doesn't govern "she" in the second example ("that" gets in the way).

Comment: What does that have to do with 'G asymmetrically c-commands B' of government's definition?

Comment: @AshleyYoon "that" asymmetrically c-commands "she".

Comment: It's too hard... Then what are the differences between definition of government that contains 'G asymmetrically c-commands B' and that doesn't in example 'John saw that she was there.'?

Comment: @AshleyYoon If you leave out that line, then "saw" governs "she". We don't want that, because the point of government is to explain why the object of a verb becomes "her" rather than "she" (we say that if "she" is governed by a verb, it becomes "her").

Comment: I understand that NP (John) phrase-governs NP (she) since V and C doesn't count as interveners, but if the expression ''G asymmetrically c-commands B'' is gone, NP (John) cannot govern NP (she). Is it right...?

Comment: @AshleyYoon The "G asymmetrically c-commands B" phrase means you can't have an intervening head: you can't have any other head that commands B and is commanded by A. I'm not sure how else to explain it.